# How do I align text so it has equal left and right indentation in overleaf?

Tags: align, overleaf

When I compile my document on Overleaf, the rows of text have each different lengths. I'd like the text to be aligned the same way as it is in Word when using the `justified` alignment option. Should I use `\justify` for each paragraph or is there maybe some global function, so that all the text is justified?

Here is an example of the document. My writing language is not English and in the real document the alignment looks much worse. In this example the uneven indentation is not so apparent. I added everything I have before the beginning of the document, because I have no idea what causes the text to be so uneven.

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \date{}
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{babel,etoolbox, lineno}
    \renewcommand*\contentsname{Contents}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{babel,graphicx}
    \usepackage[english]{biblatex}
    \newtheorem{definition}{Definiton}
    \addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
    \setstretch{1.5}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{a4paper, portrait, margin=20mm, bmargin=20mm, tmargin=30mm}
    \setlength{\parindent}{4em}
    \begin{document}
    
    
    
    
    \newpage
    \section{Introduction}
    
    The trimming proportion is selected as follows. Consider a characteristic $Sn(a, F)$ of the distribution of $T(a, Fn)$, usually a measure of spread. Here we either mean the finite-sample distribution or the asymptotic distribution. In the latter case, the subscript n will later be omitted. As a concrete example, suppose $Sn(a, F)$ is the exact variance under$F$ of $T(a, Fn)$. The idea consists of estimating $Sn(a, F)$
    
    
    \newpage
    \renewcommand{\refname}{References}
    \printbibliography
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805).

Comment: By default latex uses justified alignment so, I don't understand why you get a ragged text, but as @JoséCarlosSantos mentioned, an MWE will clear that up.

Comment: @DhruvThakkar I added a working example. In reality the text I have is way more unequally aligned.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have added a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply stop using the `ragged2e` package. By using it, you are asking LaTeX *not* to justify the lines.